Aurora Postgresql - data migration using pg_dump
I have 2 Aurora postgresql DB (A and B), sitting under 2 different Aurora clusters. In order to migrate data(only) from DB A to DB B, do I need to install pg_dump extension on the clusters, or just need to install it on the local machine (or the jumphost) where the connection to the cluster is established?
I don’t have direct access to the production cluster so not able to test.
But I can apply for jumphost access if pg_dump is only needed there. Thanks.

pg_dump is a client tool, so you don't need to install anything on the database server to use it. Install the PostgreSQL client on your local machine, and make sure to use the same (major) version as you are using on the database servers.
